# How do I get a HTML drop down to start lower

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, dropdown

The website I've been working on I've been very picking with everything, because I want this to be a very cleaned and good website for my first professional job. The only item that has been annoying me is that my navbar has hover-drop-down and it overlaps with the company's logo. I wanted to know if there was a way in CSS to get the dropdown to begin about 12px lower?

```
<div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12  text-left-xs text-left-sm ">
                        <div class="bar__module" >
                            <ul class="menu-horizontal ">
                                <li class="dropdown dropdown--hover "><a href="/motors/shop.aspx">Shop</a><span class="dropdown__trigger"></span>
                                    <div class="dropdown__container">
                                        <div class="container">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="dropdown__content col-md-12 text-left" style="background: linear-gradient(#E9E9E9, #ffffff);">
                                                    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs ">
                                                        <img alt="" src="../photosvideos/sidewindernewpics/Sw shield side copy.png" style="margin-bottom: -18px;" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-left">
                                                        <h5>Products</h5>
                                                        <ul class="menu-vertical">
                                                            <li><a href="/motors">About The Sidewinder</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="/motors/shop.aspx">Shop</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
```

[Example of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3vHC.png)

[I want that edge to be lower so that it doesn't touch the logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qVLq.png)

Comment: use `margin-top` or  position the element anything but static and use `top`.  Or put `padding-top` on the parent

Comment: If you post the code maybe we can help you fix it. Right now all we can do is guess what your code needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are in fact *multiple* ways to move an element down 12px in CSS:

- By using `margin-top: 12px`
- By using `padding-top: 12px`
- By using `border-top: 12px solid transparent` (or dashed, dotted, etc.)
- By using `relative` position and `top: 12px`
- By using `absolute` position and `top: 12px`
- By using `fixed` position and `top: 12px`
- By using `transform: translateY(12px)`

Without any more code, it's much harder to tell you which of these solutions is best for your case.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've never written a Stack-overflow question myself, but My problem is I can't seem to figure out in what element do I need to add the margin/padding/border to get my desired result.

Comment: I don't know the other styles in your page, but I'd try to change either of these: `dropdown__container` or `content` or `row` or `dropdown__content`. It looks as if you're using some sort of framework (bootstrap?), so _don't change their code_ – you'll want to have things you've changed in your own CSS file, because otherwise you loose all your changes when you update the framework. Most probably, I'd add a special class to the element I need to change and apply my changes via that class.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without an illustration of the problem, also you should include some code to make it easier to understand and help you fix your problem.

Anyways to move an element down on a page, there is several ways. One, and probably the most common is to use margin-top.

```
.moveDown 
{
   margin-top: 12px;
}
```

If your dropdown/ element doesn't move it might have something to do with the position you have designed it to (hard for me to answer without any code/ pics to look at...)